# How to check my account on embedded linux without "/etc/passwd"?

Tags: linux, ssh, password, embedded, dropbear

On some embedded linux systems, there is no `/etc/passwd` file and `/etc` directory is not writable (which means I cannot set user account and password?).

Then what is my (default) account name and password, or how to set account and password? I need to get account and password on embedded linux to run `ssh` server, which requires user account and password for `ssh` login.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "some embedded linux systems"...

Comment: @Floyd embedded linux running on embedded devices such as router, switch,  and so on.

Comment: @kolar - embedded linux running on any device will be configured to handle whatever users / authentications it is configured to handle. If your device runs linux *and* the entity that put it on that device respects the licensing, you should be able to request from them or otherwise obtain a source code copy of their configuration.

Comment: You really should provide more details as the type of hardware and OS you're using if you want relevant answers.

You may not modify the passwd file by hand, but there should be a passwd command that would take care of updating a p/w for a specific user.

Also if you're listing the filesystem, you must be connected onto the board, via root login?

Comment: I am connected to the target board but the connection does not require login. Also there is no passwd command on the target board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no `/etc/passwd`, then your embedded system is not running what is usually known as the Linux system, but rather a different operating system which is also based on the Linux kernel. A famous example of an operating system which uses on the Linux kernel but is not Linux is Android. Android doesn't have user accounts (at least not in its basic usage) and repurposes users to isolate applications rather than accounts.

Such embedded systems are generally not meant to have user accounts. They have at most a control console, which is solely intended for administration and allows running commands as root. There may be authentication in some form, or the fact that you have physical access may be considered sufficient authentication. There's no general rule there, you have to know (or find out) how your system is designed.

If you want to connect with SSH, you'll have to [supply credentials to the SSH servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147366/how-to-connect-to-ssh-server-running-on-embedded-linux-without-etc-passwd).