# How to connect to ssh-server running on embedded linux without /etc/passwd?

Tags: ssh, embedded, accounts, dropbear

After installing ssh server on my remote machine (which runs embedded Linux), I tried to connect to ssh server from host machine but it failed.

This is because I could not specify user account when connecting to ssh-server (ssh connection requires to enter password of an account) since my target embedded Linux does not have `/etc/passwd` and `/etc` is not writable. Thus there are no user accounts on that system.

Do we have alternative ways to connect to ssh-server on remote machine from host machine? I want to log in as the root user.

This question is a follow-up to my previous question [How to check my account on embedded linux without "/etc/passwd"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147359/how-to-check-my-account-on-embedded-linux-without-etc-passwd)

Comment: If there are no accounts on the remote machine, what exactly do you expect to happen when you connect?

Comment: Do you want to log in as root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropbear calls the [`getpwnam`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam) standard library function to get information about user accounts. On systems with GNU libc (the standard library for non-embedded Linux systems), this function can query several types of databases through the [NSS mechanism](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf), including [`/etc/passwd`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd). Embedded systems may run a variety of libc (uClibc, dietlibc, …), and they tend to have the path `/etc/passwd` baked in.

Short of patching and recompiling dropbear (or your libc), you're going to have to supply that `/etc/passwd` file somehow. There are ways to make extra files appear on top of a read-only filesystem, not by modifying the filesystem, but instead by instructing the kernel to supply files from a different filesystem at these locations. The generic mechanism is a [union mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount), but embedded Linux systems often lack a good union mount feature.

A relatively simply way to override a filesystem location with different content is `mount --bind`. After running the command `mount --bind /else/where` /some/where`, any access to a file`/some/where/somefile`actually accesses the file`/else/where/somefile`; any file in the “true”`/else/where`is hidden. However, you cannot directly make a file appear this way: both`/else/where`and`/some/where`have to exist (although they don't have to be directories). So you can't make`/etc/passwd`come into existence, but you can override`/etc`.

1. Create a directory that will contain your replacement for `/etc`. Let's say it's `/custom/etc`.

   ```
   mkdir /custom/etc
   ```
2. Create a mount point where you'll relocate the original `/etc/`.

   ```
   mkdir /custom/original-etc
   ```
3. Create symbolic links in the replacement `etc` to files in the original.

   ```
   cd /etc
   for x in *; do ln -s "../original-etc/$x" "/custom/etc/$x"; done
   ```
4. Create a `passwd` file in your replacement `etc` hierarchy.

   ```
   echo "root:x:0:0:root:/:/bin/sh" >/custom/etc/passwd
   ```

At boot time, first perform a bind mount to create a view of the original `/etc` hierarchy at `/custom/original-etc`, then perform a bind mount to create a view of your replacement `/etc` at `/etc`. Put these commands in a script that is executed during startup (the same script where you start the dropbear server, obviously before starting dropbear).

```
mount --bind /etc /custom/original-etc
mount --bind /custom/etc /etc
```

Comment: probably `/etc/fstab` would be a pretty convenient way of configuring a boottime mount option?

Comment: @mikeserv Well, yes, if you could modify `/etc` in the first place. It's the read-only `/etc` that requires this whole rigmarole.

Comment: You can - *maybe* in initramfs. Still, that is not a remark on the quality of this answer - which is excellent. Though, these days there is nothing you can do with a union mount that you cannt do with mount namespaces and private/shared/bind mounts and the rest.

Comment: Before you answered, I first tried to modify dropbear src by writing fake getpwnam. However, dropbear din't work on my device since it additionally requires /etc/group file, which is used by initgroups function in dropbear src. Thus I decided to use your approach, and it works! Thank you so much!